# Difference between bounds.size.width and bounds.width in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

What is the difference between `bounds.size.width` and `bounds.width` in swift? Will they return the same thing?
Thanks!

Comment: What is a `bounds` object?  What does the documentation say?

Comment: I think Aaron's answer below is correct and should probably be marked as such. As an aside we apparently should not be directly accessing either but using CGRectGetWidth to avoid negative numbers (see SO question 'CGRectGetWidth vs CGRect.size.width').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bounds` is a `CGRect` struct property for a UIView that contains 2 nested structs within it; `CGPoint` and `CGSize`. These represent the points of origin for the view (x and y), and the size of the view in height and width specified in points respectively.

If you have a UIView that's 100 x 100, then: `bounds.width` will return 100, and `bounds.size.width` will also return 100. Basically they will return the same `CGFloat` values even if your `CGRect` has negative width and height values.